# In plain tex, how to use Small Caps in equations?

Tags: plain-tex

In LaTeX, we can write

> `$T_{\textsc{max}}$`

In plain TeX, we can do thing like

> `\font\scshape=cmcsc10`
>
> `{\scashape max}`.

But this method does not work inside $$. We cannot write

> `$T_{{\scshape max}}$`

So is there any way to make it work?

Comment: `$T_{\hbox{\scshape max}}$` should work …

Comment: Perhaps $T_{\hbox{\scriptsize\scshape max}}}$

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel that would make a textsize subscript though.

Comment: @Aditya  `\scriptsize` isn't in plain.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, it was more of a pointer than a solution. Op didn’t define any other fonts to use …

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

```
    \font\scshapex=cmcsc10
    \font\scshapevii=cmcsc10 at 7pt
    \font\scshapev=cmcsc10 at 5pt

\newfam\scfam
\textfont\scfam\scshapex
\scriptfont\scfam\scshapevii
\scriptscriptfont\scfam\scshapev



$    {\fam\scfam Max}(T) = T_{\fam\scfam Max} $

\bye
```

Answer (score 9):

Without defining a math family:

```
\font\tensc=cmcsc10
\font\sevensc=cmcsc10 at 7pt
\font\fivesc=cmcsc10 at 5pt

\def\mathsc#1{{\mathchoice
  {\hbox{\tensc#1}}
  {\hbox{\tensc#1}}
  {\hbox{\sevensc#1}}
  {\hbox{\fivesc#1}}
}}

$\mathsc{Max}(T) = T_\mathsc{Max}$

\bye
```

[image]